# Evaluate the integral of $\cos(x^2+y^2)$ over a certain region

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Evaluate

$$
\int_{-2}^2 dx \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^\sqrt{4-x^2} dy \ \cos(x^2+y^2).
$$

Does it make sense to use substitution and set $u=x^2+y^2$? I'd then get $\sin(x^2+y^2)$ evaluated from $-\sqrt{4-x^2}$ to $\sqrt{4-x^2}$?

Comment: When I do this first integral I get $0$, which I don't think is right

Comment: $\sin(x^2)$ famously does not have an elementary antiderivative, so anything you did on that front can't be right.

Comment: That's what I thought and then tried to work through it, and resulted in $0$

Comment: So that means you'll have to do something else to solve this. Perhaps you've learned something more recently that can help you. Hint: What does the region of integration look like?

Comment: $-2\leq x\leq 2$, $-\sqrt{4-x^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$

Comment: That's what the problem says, yes, but I need you to go deeper than that. What would that *look* like if you were to draw it in the $xy$ plane?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109605/discussion-between-wng427-and-ninad-munshi).

Answer (score 2):

In double integrals which offer themselves for conversion to radial forms, one must.
If you look at the limits of the integral, you can see that, you are integrating the function over a circle of radius 2 units, because $y = -\sqrt(4-x^2)$ to $y = \sqrt(4-x^2)$ . Squaring both of which would give, $y^2 + x^2 = 4$.

Recall, that $dydx$ in radial form becomes $rdrd\theta$

So the integral becomes $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} Cos(r^2)rdrd\theta$

A substitution of $r^2$ as $t$, will make it an easy resolution because of the $rdr$ present outside.